# Instance member 'items' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: flutter, dart

like in the title i don't understand what should i do. I saw something on internet but i don't know how to use it in this case. I would also like to know how it's working if it is possible.

```
final items = List<DateTime>.generate(60, (i) =>
      DateTime.utc(
        DateTime.now().year,
        DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day,
      ).add(Duration(days: i)
      )
  );
```

:

```
items: Dashboard.items.map((i) {
        return Builder(
(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the access (it this case you have to be accessing `items` from the class body):

```dart
items: items.map((i) {
        return Builder(
(...)
```

or change the field definition (by adding `static`):

```dart
static final items = List<DateTime>.generate(60, (i) =>
      DateTime.utc(
        DateTime.now().year,
        DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day,
      ).add(Duration(days: i)
      )
  );
```

I would go with the first option everyday but it's your choice ;)